# Switch no cambia el color del fondo JS

Tags: javascript

Necesito entregar un ejercicio estrictamente con switch, y no entiendo porque al introducir un color, el cuál especifico, no cambia de color o solo cambia a color negro. Quiero que al introducir un color en la caja de texto (negro, azul o amarillo), cambien a estos según sean mencionados.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda y un saludo.
Este es el código en cuestión:

```
<body id=cuerpo>
<p>Elige un color (negro - azul - amarillo)</p>
<input type="text" id="dato" maxlength="10" /><br><br>
<input type="button" value="APLICAR" onclick="cambiocolor()" />


<script>
    function cambiocolor() {
        let campo = document.getElementById("dato").value;

        let prueba = document.getElementById("cuerpo");
        switch (true) {
            case campo = 'negro':
                cuerpo.style.background = "black";
                break;
            case campo = 'amarillo':
                cuerpo.style.background = "yellow";
                break;
            case campo = 'azul':
                cuerpo.style.background = "blue";
                break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que el swithc, lo estás utilizando mal, tienes que poner entre parentesis con lo que quieres comparar: Vas a tener que cambiar el `True` que tienes puesto, por tu variable `campo`, y de esta manera luego podrás compararlo con cada caso:

```
<body id=cuerpo>
    <p>Elige un color (negro - azul - amarillo)</p>
    <input type="text" id="dato" maxlength="10" /><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="APLICAR" onclick="cambiocolor()" />


    <script>
        function cambiocolor() {
            let campo = document.getElementById("dato").value;

            let prueba = document.getElementById("cuerpo");

            switch (campo) {
                case campo = 'negro':
                    cuerpo.style.background = "black";
                    break;
                case campo = 'amarillo':
                    cuerpo.style.background = "yellow";
                    break;
                case campo = 'azul':
                    cuerpo.style.background = "blue";
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

También quiero aprovechar para decirte que no cierras la etiqueta `</body>`

Copiando el código, te debería de funcionar. Un saludo

Comment: Buenos días, el body no entiendo por que no se aplicaba en el Ctrl + K, así que lo borré en caso de que hubiera algún error. Siguiendo con switch, he intentado lo que me dices y no cambia de color, solo a negro pero sin seguir las instrucciones que le indicas. Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Has probado a copiar, y pegar el código que te he pasado? Yo lo he probado en mi ordenador y funciona correctamente. En caso de que te de error, ¿te escribe algo en la consola?

Comment: Disculpa mi error, con el filtro azul apenas distinguía el azul del negro y el amarillo del blanco. Pensé que podría ser eso así que lo cambié. Tu código es totalmente funcional. Muchas gracias y un saludo, perdona las molestias.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya funcionado. Un saludo